# No longer able to input circumflex or diaeresis accented characters (qt5 apps only !)

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, qt5

Currently running KDE-Plasma-5.23.5 (X backend)/ KDE-Frameworks-5.90.0 / QT-5.15.3
I can assert that this used to work perfectly but am unfortunately unable to assert from which version of what the problem started to occur systematically.

---

Whatever the qt5 application I launch (kmail, kate, konsole, dolphin, qtdesigner…) I am no longer able to key in the â ä ë ê î ï ô ö ü û (as well as corresponding uppercase) characters. (usually possible via hitting the dedicated dead key then the desired vowel)

Keying any other directly accessible accentuated character works fine.

I suspect this problem to be restrained to qt5-ed apps since it does not impact non qt5-ed applications such as The-Gimp, Firefox, Chromium, Yoshimi (fltk), my Arduino prototyping platform, audacity… all launched from the same user under the same DE.

---

**UPDATE 1 / XMODIFIERS :**

Curiously enough, If I `export XMODIFIERS=` before launching my DE, or even within some konsole session, then, if I launch kate *manually* (via bash), the problem does not occur.
It however still occurs when starting kate from the KDE menu or clicking on its icon.
Therefore my problem would become, how should I set XMODIFIERS so that whatever qt5 app could automagically honour it ?
BTW, unless I export it explicitly, this variable is not part of the environment when my DE is running.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found (per pure chance).
However it sounds so absurd to me that I cannot accept it as The answer.

Hence do not hesitate to post another answer suggesting another more logical way to proceed or explaining what is happening or if this is a deliberate will from devs. Whatever, I'll be more pleased awarding the bounty to anyone than having 50 Kudos lost for everybody.

---

**Solution :** Simply select the appropriate *region* in system settings / Regional Settings / Format (In this occurrence fr_FR)

---

Tl;Dr mostly rant :

**A/** I had this previously set to "No change", assuming that implicitly meant "no change from active X settings when starting KDE." and since whatever X application started outside of KDE as well as whatever non-qt5 application launched from the desktop were just happy…

So : *No change* ? But from what actually ?

**B/** Why does changes made for that setting only concern qt5 applications ?
Because they use some different input method ?
As far as I can tell, since I don't use gnome, I build qtgui with support for only good old *libinput* and *evdev*. v.g without support for *ibus*. Not to say that the ibus-daemon is not running on my system.

**C/** Why are the settings found under system settings / input devices / keyboard (Hardware, Layout, Advanced) no longer enough to ensure desired keyboard input behaviour ? (I am quite sure they used to be)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing my language in my System settings : **Regional Settings/Region & Language/Language** to American English (it should work with an another language. My old language seemed to be outdated).