# Suckless Terminal dead keys

Tags: keyboard, suckless-terminal

I'm wondering if there is a way to make dead keys working in DWM ?
I'm actually using a *french AZERTY* keyboard:

```bash
setxkbmap fr
```

For example, I can't get the `ê` character to print in the terminal. I get `^e` instead.
I tried with several fonts, such as *Liberation Mono*, *Mononoki* or *Cascadia Mono*.
I can print this character anywhere else in my computer (text editor, web browser, etc.).

Here are my locale settings:

```
bash ~ $ locale
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Here is my st config file:

```c
/* See LICENSE file for copyright and license details. */

/*
 * appearance
 *
 * font: see http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html
 */
/*static char *font = "Liberation Mono:pixelsize=12:antialias=true:autohint=true"; */
static char *font = "Mononoki:pixelsize=20:antialias=true:autohint=true";
/* static char *font = "Cascadia Mono:pixelsize=20:antialias=true:autohint=true"; */
static int borderpx = 2;

/*
 * What program is execed by st depends of these precedence rules:
 * 1: program passed with -e
 * 2: scroll and/or utmp
 * 3: SHELL environment variable
 * 4: value of shell in /etc/passwd
 * 5: value of shell in config.h
 */
static char *shell = "/bin/bash";
char *utmp = NULL;
/* scroll program: to enable use a string like "scroll" */
char *scroll = NULL;
char *stty_args = "stty raw pass8 nl -echo -iexten -cstopb 38400";

/* identification sequence returned in DA and DECID */
char *vtiden = "\033[?6c";

/* Kerning / character bounding-box multipliers */
static float cwscale = 1.0;
static float chscale = 1.0;

/*
 * word delimiter string
 *
 * More advanced example: L" `'\"()[]{}"
 */
wchar_t *worddelimiters = L" ";

/* selection timeouts (in milliseconds) */
static unsigned int doubleclicktimeout = 300;
static unsigned int tripleclicktimeout = 600;

/* alt screens */
int allowaltscreen = 1;

/* allow certain non-interactive (insecure) window operations such as:
   setting the clipboard text */
int allowwindowops = 0;

/*
 * draw latency range in ms - from new content/keypress/etc until drawing.
 * within this range, st draws when content stops arriving (idle). mostly it's
 * near minlatency, but it waits longer for slow updates to avoid partial draw.
 * low minlatency will tear/flicker more, as it can "detect" idle too early.
 */
static double minlatency = 8;
static double maxlatency = 33;

/*
 * blinking timeout (set to 0 to disable blinking) for the terminal blinking
 * attribute.
 */
static unsigned int blinktimeout = 800;

/*
 * thickness of underline and bar cursors
 */
static unsigned int cursorthickness = 2;

/*
 * bell volume. It must be a value between -100 and 100. Use 0 for disabling
 * it
 */
static int bellvolume = 0;

/* default TERM value */
char *termname = "st-256color";

/*
 * spaces per tab
 *
 * When you are changing this value, don't forget to adapt the »it« value in
 * the st.info and appropriately install the st.info in the environment where
 * you use this st version.
 *
 *  it#$tabspaces,
 *
 * Secondly make sure your kernel is not expanding tabs. When running `stty
 * -a` »tab0« should appear. You can tell the terminal to not expand tabs by
 *  running following command:
 *
 *  stty tabs
 */
unsigned int tabspaces = 8;

/* Terminal colors (16 first used in escape sequence) */
static const char *colorname[] = {
    /* 8 normal colors */
    "black",
    "red3",
    "green3",
    "yellow3",
    "blue2",
    "magenta3",
    "cyan3",
    "gray90",

    /* 8 bright colors */
    "gray50",
    "red",
    "green",
    "yellow",
    "#5c5cff",
    "magenta",
    "cyan",
    "white",

    [255] = 0,

    /* more colors can be added after 255 to use with DefaultXX */
    "#cccccc",
    "#555555",
    "gray90", /* default foreground colour */
    "black", /* default background colour */
};


/*
 * Default colors (colorname index)
 * foreground, background, cursor, reverse cursor
 */
unsigned int defaultfg = 258;
unsigned int defaultbg = 237;
unsigned int defaultcs = 256;
static unsigned int defaultrcs = 257;

/*
 * Default shape of cursor
 * 2: Block ("█")
 * 4: Underline ("_")
 * 6: Bar ("|")
 * 7: Snowman ("☃")
 */
static unsigned int cursorshape = 2;

/*
 * Default columns and rows numbers
 */

static unsigned int cols = 80;
static unsigned int rows = 24;

/*
 * Default colour and shape of the mouse cursor
 */
static unsigned int mouseshape = XC_xterm;
static unsigned int mousefg = 7;
static unsigned int mousebg = 0;

/*
 * Color used to display font attributes when fontconfig selected a font which
 * doesn't match the ones requested.
 */
static unsigned int defaultattr = 11;

/*
 * Force mouse select/shortcuts while mask is active (when MODE_MOUSE is set).
 * Note that if you want to use ShiftMask with selmasks, set this to an other
 * modifier, set to 0 to not use it.
 */
static uint forcemousemod = ShiftMask;

/*
 * Internal mouse shortcuts.
 * Beware that overloading Button1 will disable the selection.
 */
const unsigned int mousescrollincrement = 1;
static MouseShortcut mshortcuts[] = {
    /* mask                 button   function        argument       release */
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button4, kscrollup,      {.i = 1},              0, /* !alt */ -1 },
        { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button5, kscrolldown,    {.i = 1},              0, /* !alt */ -1 },
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button2, selpaste,       {.i = 0},      1 },
    { ShiftMask,            Button4, ttysend,        {.s = "\033[5;2~"} },
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button4, ttysend,        {.s = "\031"} },
    { ShiftMask,            Button5, ttysend,        {.s = "\033[6;2~"} },
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button5, ttysend,        {.s = "\005"} },
};

/* Internal keyboard shortcuts. */
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
#define TERMMOD (ControlMask|ShiftMask)

static Shortcut shortcuts[] = {
    /* mask                 keysym          function        argument */
    { XK_ANY_MOD,           XK_Break,       sendbreak,      {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_C,           clipcopy,       {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_V,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_i,           zoom,           {.f = +1} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_o,           zoom,           {.f = -1} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_r,           zoomreset,      {.f =  0} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_Page_Up,     kscrollup,      {.i = -1} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_Page_Down,   kscrolldown,    {.i = -1} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_Up,          kscrollup,      {.i =  1} },
    { MODKEY,               XK_Down,        kscrolldown,    {.i =  1} },
};

/*
 * Special keys (change & recompile st.info accordingly)
 *
 * Mask value:
 * * Use XK_ANY_MOD to match the key no matter modifiers state
 * * Use XK_NO_MOD to match the key alone (no modifiers)
 * appkey value:
 * * 0: no value
 * * > 0: keypad application mode enabled
 * *   = 2: term.numlock = 1
 * * < 0: keypad application mode disabled
 * appcursor value:
 * * 0: no value
 * * > 0: cursor application mode enabled
 * * < 0: cursor application mode disabled
 *
 * Be careful with the order of the definitions because st searches in
 * this table sequentially, so any XK_ANY_MOD must be in the last
 * position for a key.
 */

/*
 * If you want keys other than the X11 function keys (0xFD00 - 0xFFFF)
 * to be mapped below, add them to this array.
 */
static KeySym mappedkeys[] = { -1 };

/*
 * State bits to ignore when matching key or button events.  By default,
 * numlock (Mod2Mask) and keyboard layout (XK_SWITCH_MOD) are ignored.
 */
static uint ignoremod = Mod2Mask|XK_SWITCH_MOD;

/*
 * This is the huge key array which defines all compatibility to the Linux
 * world. Please decide about changes wisely.
 */
static Key key[] = {
    /* keysym           mask            string      appkey appcursor */
    { XK_KP_Home,       ShiftMask,      "\033[2J",       0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Home,       ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2H",     0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Home,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[H",        0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Home,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[1~",       0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Up,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ox",       +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Up,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[A",        0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Up,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OA",        0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Down,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Or",       +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Down,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[B",        0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Down,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OB",        0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Left,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ot",       +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Left,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[D",        0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Left,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OD",        0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Right,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ov",       +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Right,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[C",        0,   -1},
    { XK_KP_Right,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OC",        0,   +1},
    { XK_KP_Prior,      ShiftMask,      "\033[5;2~",     0,    0},
    { XK_KP_Prior,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[5~",       0,    0},
    { XK_KP_Begin,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[E",        0,    0},
    { XK_KP_End,        ControlMask,    "\033[J",       -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_End,        ControlMask,    "\033[1;5F",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_End,        ShiftMask,      "\033[K",       -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_End,        ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2F",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_End,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[4~",       0,    0},
    { XK_KP_Next,       ShiftMask,      "\033[6;2~",     0,    0},
    { XK_KP_Next,       XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[6~",       0,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     ShiftMask,      "\033[2;2~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     ShiftMask,      "\033[4l",      -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     ControlMask,    "\033[L",       -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     ControlMask,    "\033[2;5~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[4h",      -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Insert,     XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[2~",      +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     ControlMask,    "\033[M",       -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     ControlMask,    "\033[3;5~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     ShiftMask,      "\033[2K",      -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     ShiftMask,      "\033[3;2~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[P",       -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Delete,     XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[3~",      +1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Multiply,   XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Oj",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_Add,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ok",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_Enter,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OM",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_Enter,      XK_ANY_MOD,     "\r",           -1,    0},
    { XK_KP_Subtract,   XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Om",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_Decimal,    XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033On",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_Divide,     XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Oo",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_0,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Op",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_1,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Oq",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_2,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Or",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_3,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Os",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_4,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ot",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_5,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ou",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_6,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ov",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_7,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ow",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_8,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Ox",       +2,    0},
    { XK_KP_9,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033Oy",       +2,    0},
    { XK_Up,            ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,            Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,         ShiftMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;4A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,            ControlMask,    "\033[1;5A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,      ShiftMask|ControlMask,"\033[1;6A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,       ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;7A",     0,    0},
    { XK_Up,ShiftMask|ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;8A",  0,    0},
    { XK_Up,            XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[A",        0,   -1},
    { XK_Up,            XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OA",        0,   +1},
    { XK_Down,          ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,          Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,       ShiftMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;4B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,          ControlMask,    "\033[1;5B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,    ShiftMask|ControlMask,"\033[1;6B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,     ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;7B",     0,    0},
    { XK_Down,ShiftMask|ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;8B",0,    0},
    { XK_Down,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[B",        0,   -1},
    { XK_Down,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OB",        0,   +1},
    { XK_Left,          ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,          Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,       ShiftMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;4D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,          ControlMask,    "\033[1;5D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,    ShiftMask|ControlMask,"\033[1;6D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,     ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;7D",     0,    0},
    { XK_Left,ShiftMask|ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;8D",0,    0},
    { XK_Left,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[D",        0,   -1},
    { XK_Left,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OD",        0,   +1},
    { XK_Right,         ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,         Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,      ShiftMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;4C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,         ControlMask,    "\033[1;5C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,   ShiftMask|ControlMask,"\033[1;6C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,    ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;7C",     0,    0},
    { XK_Right,ShiftMask|ControlMask|Mod1Mask,"\033[1;8C",0,   0},
    { XK_Right,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[C",        0,   -1},
    { XK_Right,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033OC",        0,   +1},
    { XK_ISO_Left_Tab,  ShiftMask,      "\033[Z",        0,    0},
    { XK_Return,        Mod1Mask,       "\033\r",        0,    0},
    { XK_Return,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\r",            0,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        ShiftMask,      "\033[4l",      -1,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        ShiftMask,      "\033[2;2~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        ControlMask,    "\033[L",       -1,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        ControlMask,    "\033[2;5~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[4h",      -1,    0},
    { XK_Insert,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[2~",      +1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        ControlMask,    "\033[M",       -1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        ControlMask,    "\033[3;5~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        ShiftMask,      "\033[2K",      -1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        ShiftMask,      "\033[3;2~",    +1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[P",       -1,    0},
    { XK_Delete,        XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[3~",      +1,    0},
    { XK_BackSpace,     XK_NO_MOD,      "\177",          0,    0},
    { XK_BackSpace,     Mod1Mask,       "\033\177",      0,    0},
    { XK_Home,          ShiftMask,      "\033[2J",       0,   -1},
    { XK_Home,          ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2H",     0,   +1},
    { XK_Home,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[H",        0,   -1},
    { XK_Home,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[1~",       0,   +1},
    { XK_End,           ControlMask,    "\033[J",       -1,    0},
    { XK_End,           ControlMask,    "\033[1;5F",    +1,    0},
    { XK_End,           ShiftMask,      "\033[K",       -1,    0},
    { XK_End,           ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2F",    +1,    0},
    { XK_End,           XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[4~",       0,    0},
    { XK_Prior,         ControlMask,    "\033[5;5~",     0,    0},
    { XK_Prior,         ShiftMask,      "\033[5;2~",     0,    0},
    { XK_Prior,         XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[5~",       0,    0},
    { XK_Next,          ControlMask,    "\033[6;5~",     0,    0},
    { XK_Next,          ShiftMask,      "\033[6;2~",     0,    0},
    { XK_Next,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[6~",       0,    0},
    { XK_F1,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033OP" ,       0,    0},
    { XK_F1, /* F13 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F1, /* F25 */  ControlMask,    "\033[1;5P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F1, /* F37 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[1;6P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F1, /* F49 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F1, /* F61 */  Mod3Mask,       "\033[1;4P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F2,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033OQ" ,       0,    0},
    { XK_F2, /* F14 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F2, /* F26 */  ControlMask,    "\033[1;5Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F2, /* F38 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[1;6Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F2, /* F50 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F2, /* F62 */  Mod3Mask,       "\033[1;4Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F3,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033OR" ,       0,    0},
    { XK_F3, /* F15 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F3, /* F27 */  ControlMask,    "\033[1;5R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F3, /* F39 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[1;6R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F3, /* F51 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F3, /* F63 */  Mod3Mask,       "\033[1;4R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F4,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033OS" ,       0,    0},
    { XK_F4, /* F16 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F4, /* F28 */  ControlMask,    "\033[1;5S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F4, /* F40 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[1;6S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F4, /* F52 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[1;3S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F5,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[15~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F5, /* F17 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[15;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F5, /* F29 */  ControlMask,    "\033[15;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F5, /* F41 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[15;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F5, /* F53 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[15;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F6,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[17~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F6, /* F18 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[17;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F6, /* F30 */  ControlMask,    "\033[17;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F6, /* F42 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[17;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F6, /* F54 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[17;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F7,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[18~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F7, /* F19 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[18;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F7, /* F31 */  ControlMask,    "\033[18;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F7, /* F43 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[18;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F7, /* F55 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[18;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F8,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[19~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F8, /* F20 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[19;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F8, /* F32 */  ControlMask,    "\033[19;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F8, /* F44 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[19;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F8, /* F56 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[19;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F9,            XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[20~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F9, /* F21 */  ShiftMask,      "\033[20;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F9, /* F33 */  ControlMask,    "\033[20;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F9, /* F45 */  Mod4Mask,       "\033[20;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F9, /* F57 */  Mod1Mask,       "\033[20;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F10,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[21~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F10, /* F22 */ ShiftMask,      "\033[21;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F10, /* F34 */ ControlMask,    "\033[21;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F10, /* F46 */ Mod4Mask,       "\033[21;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F10, /* F58 */ Mod1Mask,       "\033[21;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F11,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[23~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F11, /* F23 */ ShiftMask,      "\033[23;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F11, /* F35 */ ControlMask,    "\033[23;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F11, /* F47 */ Mod4Mask,       "\033[23;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F11, /* F59 */ Mod1Mask,       "\033[23;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F12,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[24~",      0,    0},
    { XK_F12, /* F24 */ ShiftMask,      "\033[24;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F12, /* F36 */ ControlMask,    "\033[24;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F12, /* F48 */ Mod4Mask,       "\033[24;6~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F12, /* F60 */ Mod1Mask,       "\033[24;3~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F13,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;2P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F14,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;2Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F15,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;2R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F16,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;2S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F17,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[15;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F18,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[17;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F19,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[18;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F20,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[19;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F21,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[20;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F22,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[21;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F23,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[23;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F24,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[24;2~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F25,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;5P",     0,    0},
    { XK_F26,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;5Q",     0,    0},
    { XK_F27,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;5R",     0,    0},
    { XK_F28,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[1;5S",     0,    0},
    { XK_F29,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[15;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F30,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[17;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F31,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[18;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F32,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[19;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F33,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[20;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F34,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[21;5~",    0,    0},
    { XK_F35,           XK_NO_MOD,      "\033[23;5~",    0,    0},
};

/*
 * Selection types' masks.
 * Use the same masks as usual.
 * Button1Mask is always unset, to make masks match between ButtonPress.
 * ButtonRelease and MotionNotify.
 * If no match is found, regular selection is used.
 */
static uint selmasks[] = {
    [SEL_RECTANGULAR] = Mod1Mask,
};

/*
 * Printable characters in ASCII, used to estimate the advance width
 * of single wide characters.
 */
static char ascii_printable[] =
    " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?"
    "@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_"
    "`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
```

**EDIT 1**:

My operating system is CalculateLinux (Gentoo based).
I tried in XTerm, and the dead keys work as expected (I get `ê`).

There are the two different behaviors:

- When working as expected, I press the `^` key once. Nothing happens, then I press `e` and I get `ê`.
- What happens in the *suckless-terminal* is that I press `^`, it immediately displays `^`, then I press `e`, so I get `^e` as a final result.

NB: the same behavior occurs with `ë` and `¨e` for example, as with all other dead keys accents.

Comment: Would this help ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706150/no-longer-able-to-input-circumflex-or-diaeresis-accented-characters-qt5-apps-on

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention you give to my question. I do not have access to my machine right now, but I will try X modifiers. As I'm in DWM, I cannot select the language settings via GUI, but I'm sure your question (and answer) will help me finding a solution !

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late reply... I tried to set `XMODIFIERS=`, before `startx` and this worked ! So I added it to my `.xinitrc`
Thank you so much ! (I upvoted your question / answer)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution comes from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706150/no-longer-able-to-input-circumflex-or-diaeresis-accented-characters-qt5-apps-on), thanks to @MC68020.

I needed to add

```bash
export XMODIFIERS=
```

before

```bash
exec dwm
```

into my `.xinitrc`.
If anyone has other solution, do not hesitate do give it here !

Comment: happy it worked for you ! +1