# Can't type the ^ character in the terminal but can use it in GUI applications

Tags: shell, arch-linux, terminal, manjaro, keyboard-layout

I use Manjaro, with i3, but the problem is also present with Plasma.
For this message, I will call the <kbd>^</kbd> (caret) key, the key on the right on the p, where a "^" and "¨" is printed and that can be used to type either "^" or "¨". Since today, I can't type either "^" or "¨" using the <kbd>^</kbd> key either in the terminal or in any terminal application. This doesn't work even if I press space or right after it.

I tried with another terminal (kitty) and the same problem exists. Nevertheless the <kbd>^</kbd> key works perfectly in non-terminal applications such as Firefox or Discord. Also I can type the `^` character in the terminal using the altgr+9 keyboard combination.

The solution:

For some reason, the keyboard variant had changed, so I just had to change the file `/etc/default/keyboards` that is now:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="kinesis"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Note that:

- I don't understand what really happened (Was the default French variant without the ^ key before, or was my keyboard layout changed by an update or something like that?)
- I don't understand why the caret key was still detected by Firefox, Discord, etc. with this configuration.

Comment: On an azerty keyboard, are you typing it with Alt-Gr + 9 , or with the dead key ^ + space? Are both not working?

Comment: I did'nt think of that :D.
I can write "^" in terminal throught this combinaison.
But it is still a big problem for me to not be able to use the keyboard touch "¨ ^" to write it!
I updated the question.

Comment: And typing the ^ key (to the right of the p key) followed by the space bar (since it's a *dead* key) doesn't work? That's the expected way for dead keys.

Comment: No. It doesn't work on terminal or terminal-applications.
It works perfectly on firefox or discord though.
I edited with your questions and used your term "^-key" to clarify my question.

Comment: Could https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706150/no-longer-able-to-input-circumflex-or-diaeresis-accented-characters-qt5-apps-on be related ?